# Moment returns an invalid date even when the format is passed

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have a string of the format "DD-MMMM-YYYY" ("18-April-2020").  So, In my app I create a moment object of the string using the code below,

```js
moment(dob, "DD-MMMM-YYYY")
```

So the problem is when I get dob from my api, moment is failing to return a valid object.This is the object I get as shown in  [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RT9XY.png)

But, If I got to momentjs website and go to their console and use  the same string I got from api with the same format , I get a valid object from moment [See this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIe1N.png)

Comment: Can you post the code for which you have assigned the ``dob`` variable?

Comment: Check the version that you are using

Comment: I advise you to fork [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/moment-js-playground) and provide a reproducible example. It will be easier helping you in working and editable code

Comment: What `locale`is cofigured/used in `moment`? What are the known monthnames in that configuration?

Comment: @Thomas I am using bn(bengali) locale but I want the moment format comparison as shown in the code  to happen with respect to english month. I think that's what causing problem

Comment: What about serialization? Should the month names there be in english or in bengali?

Comment: For this I want it to be in english